# How to listen to a container that uses a Label to display images

Tags: codenameone

How to listen to a container that uses a Label to display images.

I have created a class that inherits a container and displays images in sequence within a Label component.

I want to modify the code of the class so that it loops through a list of the image name and the URL that should be executed when the container is pressed.

An alternative would be to use a button instead of the Label component and use the "setLeadComponent" method but I'm not sure how to vary the images. Also thank you tell me the command to execute the URL.

The class has the following code.

```
public class Imagenes extends Container {

    Resources datosMundial;

    public Imagenes(Resources datosMundial) {
        this.datosMundial = datosMundial;
        muestraImagenes();
    }

    private void muestraImagenes() {
        Label lbInicio = new Label(datosMundial.getImage("p.png"));
        lbInicio.getStyle().setAlignment(Label.CENTER);
        this.addComponent(lbInicio);
        
        while (true) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                Label lb = null;
                lb = new Label(datosMundial.getImage("p" + i + ".png"));
                lb.getStyle().setAlignment(Label.CENTER);
                Component lbActual = this.getComponentAt(0);
                int aleatorio = aleatorio(5);
                if (aleatorio == 1) {
                    this.replaceAndWait(lbActual, lb, CommonTransitions.createSlide(CommonTransitions.SLIDE_VERTICAL, true, 5000));
                }
                if (aleatorio == 2) {
                    this.replaceAndWait(lbActual, lb, CommonTransitions.createCover(CommonTransitions.SLIDE_HORIZONTAL, true, 5000));
                }
                if (aleatorio == 3) {
                    this.replaceAndWait(lbActual, lb, CommonTransitions.createFade(5000));
                }
                if (aleatorio == 4) {
                    this.replaceAndWait(lbActual, lb, CommonTransitions.createCover(CommonTransitions.SLIDE_VERTICAL, true, 5000));
                }
                if (aleatorio == 5) {
                    this.replaceAndWait(lbActual, lb, CommonTransitions.createSlide(CommonTransitions.SLIDE_HORIZONTAL, true, 5000));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private int aleatorio(int x) {
        int num = 0;
        Random r = new Random();
        num = r.nextInt(x) + 1;
        return num;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the question. Do you want to make the labels clickable? Why not just make them into a button? You can make the button look like a label by invoking `lb.setUIID("Label");`.